# How to use javascript to move an object from one list to another on the same page

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp I'm working on and I was wondering if there is an easy javascript function that can figure out which element in a list is selected and then move that element to another on the same jsp?

here is the screen shot of the jsp:

[image]

this is the code:

```
<% Venue v = (Venue)session.getAttribute("currentVenue"); %>
<% List<Conceptual_Package> cpList = Conceptual_PackageDAO.getInstance().getByVenue(v.getId()); %>

What Packages do you want to see?

 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.Sale3PackAction.action">
 <select name="packid" id="packid">
     <% for (Conceptual_Package cp: cpList) { %>
    <option value="<%=cp.getId()%>"><%=cp.getName1()%></option>
    <% } %>


 </select>

    <input type="button" value="  next  " onclick="getSeats();"/>

    </form>


<!--new-->


Available Seats:

 <select name="eventSeatid" size="10" id="aSeats">

<!--    <option value="aSeats"></option>-->

 </select>


    <input type="button" value="  Add  "/>


Selected Seats:
 <form method="post" action="ttp.actions.sale4Action.action">
     <select name="eventSeat2id" size="10" id="seat2">


     <option value="seat2"></option>




 </select>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested it, but something along the lines of

```
var option = document.getElementById("....").parentElement.removeChild;
document.getElementsByName("seat2")[0].appendChild(option);
```

Comment: Getting this error in the javascript debugger: ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined
addToCartttp.actions.Sale2Action.action:86
(anonymous function)ttp.actions.Sale2Action.action:122``
onclick

Comment: @Jim Blackler I'm going to add this and see if it works better: ``var option = seat2.appendChild(document.createElement("option"));`` let me know what you think...

Comment: `document.getElementById("....")` was a placeholder for the real id or element which would need to be calculated or inferred by the logic of the item selection code. I only gave a partial solution, the bit that would actually move the DOM element representing the option.

Comment: I see. Well my big problem now is to figure out which element in the list is selected. The elements have values associated to their index in the list but I'm not sure use that to get the selected item.

Comment: Removing an element from one parent when adding to another is unnecessary. The browser will automatically do it for you, so just get a reference to the element you want to move and append it to its new parent

Comment: @meouw wow you are right. haha thanks for the info... no need to clutter up my already crazy code with unnecessary remove functions

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the SELECT field using the browser DOM, one of the fields available will be a array of Option. Each option has a value and a text to show. Just create the option to show in the new list. In the old list, set it to NULL (or move later items in the array a position before).

BTW, this has nothing to do with java or jsp.